# SED: How to remove every 10 lines in a file (thin or subsample the file)

Tags: sed, subsampling

I have this so far:

```
sed -n '0,10p' yourfile > newfile
```

But it is not working, just outputs a blank file :(

Comment: Please provide a sample input and expected output. "Remove every 10 lines" is rather ambiguous...

Comment: do you want every ***10th*** line removed, or you just want the first 10 lines of a file or you want to see only the 10th line of each file?

Comment: out of curiosity, which of the 1-liners in my answer were you looking for?

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369181/printing-every-nth-line-out-of-a-large-file-into-a-new-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous, so here is every permutation I can think of:

#### Print only the first 10 lines

```
head -n10 yourfile > newfile
```

#### Skip the first 10 lines

```
tail -n+10 yourfile > newfile
```

#### Print every 10th line

```
awk '!(NR%10)' yourfile > newfile
```

#### Delete every 10th line

```
awk 'NR%10' yourfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 3):

(Since an ambiguous questions can only have an ambiguous answer...)

To *print* every tenth line (GNU `sed`):

```
$ seq 1 100 | sed -n '0~10p'
10
20
30
40
...
100
```

Alternatively (GNU `sed`):

```
$ seq 1 100 | sed '0~10!d'
10
20
30
40
...
100
```

To *delete* every tenth line (GNU `sed`):

```
$ seq 1 100 | sed '0~10d'
1
...
9
11
...
19
21
...
29
31
...
39
41
...
```

To *print* the first ten lines (POSIX):

```
$ seq 1 100 | sed '11,$d'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

To *delete* the first ten lines (POSIX):

```
$ seq 1 100 | sed '1,10d'
11
12
13
14
...
100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python -c "import sys;sys.stdout.write(''.join(line for i, line in enumerate(open('yourfile')) if i%10 == 0 ))" >newfile
```

It is longer, but it is a single language - not different syntax and aprameters for each thing one tries to do.

Answer (score 0):

With non-GNU `sed`, to print every 10th line use

`sed '10,${p;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;}'`

(GNU : `sed -n '0~10p'`)

and to delete every 10th line use

`sed 'n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;d;'`

(GNU : `sed -n '0~10d'`)